# insert events in to a calendar, no two events can take place in a week logn

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree

Insert events in to a calendar, no two events can take place in a week, `N` is the number of events:

1. Insert in `log N` considering the week rule no two events in 7 days.
2. Given two days(`x`, `y`) inclusive return the events(`k`: events) in `O(k + log N)` between `x` day and `y` day.
3. Given a day `x` that is impossible to insert the event(week rule), find next possible `y` day `y > x` in `log N`.

I am think RB-tree, but if I have a day that is impossible to insert, finding next possible day takes `n*logn`.

Comment: No 2 events in 7 days or no 2 events in a week starting on Sunday?

Comment: Or, more likely in (parts of?) Europe, no 2 events in a week starting on Monday?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that a solution based on an RB-tree will be fine, and the main point is to use the first day of the week as the key for events that are put in the tree. Of course you need to store the actual day of the event as well.